# XQuery document node test with an element node test in BaseX 8.2 throws in the presence of comments before the root element. Why?

Tags: xml, xslt, xquery, saxon, basex

In BaseX 8.2, I'm trying to assign to an XQuery variable, a document node whose root element has a specific name. The source XML looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--A comment-->
<myRootElement/>
```

To get the document node, I type-check it using a *DocumentTest*:

```
declare variable $docnode as document-node(element(myRootElement)) := doc("pathToSourceFile");
```

However, I get the following error message: XPTY0004: Cannot treat document-node() as document-node(document-node()(myRootElement))...

This is quite unexpected because **the assignment succeeds** if there's no comment before the root element <myRootElement>. This means that the presence of the comment makes the query to fail.

However, that is not the expected behavior, unless XQuery behaves differently than XSLT in this respect (please let me know if this is the case). In XSLT, according to Michael Kay (p.671 ¶6 XSLT 2.0 and
XPath 2.0 4th Ed.) the *DocumentTest* checks the following:

> The document node must be the root of a tree that corresponds to a well-formed XML document.
>   Specifically this means that the document node must have exactly one element node, and no text
>   nodes, among its children. It is allowed to have **comments** and processing instructions before or
>   after the element node.

In fact, the following transformation on Saxon, with the same input XML works well:

```
<xsl:transform version="3.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" >
  <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="utf-8"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:variable name="docnode" as="document-node(element(myRootElement))" select="."/>
    <xsl:value-of select="$docnode/*/name(.)"/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

The assignment to variable `docnode` succeeds, and the output is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>myRootElement
```

So, why does a *DocumentTest* with an *ElementTest* on an XML document with a comment before the root element works in Saxon, but not in BaseX? Maybe, there's something new for me to learn about XQuery.

Comment: Saxon does XQuery as well so you can compare the results you have with a different processor. It sounds like a bug in BaseX however.

Comment: This indeed sounds like a bug (although I'm not too deep into the XML and XQuery specifications), you might want to ask on the [BaseX mailing list](https://mailman.uni-konstanz.de/mailman/listinfo/basex-talk).

Comment: I agree, it looks like a BaseX bug. BaseX is normally highly conformant, so this is unusual and I'm sure they'll want to know about it.

Comment: @MartinHonnen: Indeed, the comparison would have been better by running the same query on Saxon (and I just tested it works as well). I forgot entirely that Saxon also processes XQuery. Guess it's consumer behavior: in my mind, XQuery maps to BaseX, and XSLT maps to Saxon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As indicated in the comments, you got everything right. The bug has been resolved in the [latest 8.2.1 snapshot](http://files.basex.org/releases/latest/). Thanks for reporting this.